# Notation for elementwise matrix binary operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, matrices

Given two matricies A and B of equal dimensions what notation should be used to express elementwise addition, subtraction, multiplication, and so on?

Answer (score 3):

Addition (+) and subtraction (-) are already elementwise by definitions, and the elementwise multiplication of two matrices is the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29), denoted by $\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\textbf A=\textbf A_{n\times n}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}&\dots&a_{1\times n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n\times1}&\dots&a_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix},\qquad\textbf B=\textbf B_{n\times n}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{1,1}&\dots&b_{1\times n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\b_{n\times1}&\dots&b_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}$$

Element-wise addation
$$\textbf A +\textbf B=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}+b_{1,1}&\dots&a_{1\times n}+b_{1\times n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n\times1}+b_{n\times1}&\dots&a_{n\times n}+b_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}$$

Element-wise subtraction
$$\textbf A -\textbf B=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}-b_{1,1}&\dots&a_{1\times n}-b_{1\times n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n\times1}-b_{n\times1}&\dots&a_{n\times n}-b_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}$$

Element-wise multiplication
$$\textbf A \circ\textbf B=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}\times b_{1,1}&\dots&a_{1\times n}\times b_{1\times n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n\times1}\times b_{n\times1}&\dots&a_{n\times n}\times b_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is Matlab notation.

Comment: The notation $(A+B)_{ij} := a_{ij}+b_{ij}$ seems to be way more common, at least from my experience.